# How to compute the characteristic function $\mathbb{E}(e^{itXY})$ via the conditional characteristic function $\mathbb{E}(e^{itXY} \mid X)$?

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $X, Y$ be independet $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ RVs. Compute the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}(e^{itXY} \mid X)$ and use this to compute $\mathbb{E}(e^{itXY})$.

My attempt was the following:

Using a well-known lemma from probability theory we have

$$\mathbb{E}(e^{itXY} \mid X) = \mathbb{E}(e^{itxY})$$

Now, using the definiton of expected value and the assumption that $Y$ is standard normal, we get

$$ = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{itxy} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-y^2/2} dy$$

, but I do not see how to continue from here. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: Not exactly what you asked for, but an alternative way to compute this is to write $XY = \frac14\left( (X+Y)^2 - (X-Y)^2\right)$ and  observe that $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are iid $N(0,2)$. This requires some complex analysis though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given $X$, the $X$ in $e^{itXY}$ acts as a constant so $E[e^{itXY}|X]=e^{-t^{2}X^{2}/2}$. Hence $E[e^{itXY}]=Ee^{-t^{2}X^{2}/2}$. This can be computed easily using the fact that $\frac 1 {\sqrt {2\pi \sigma}}\int e^{-x^{2}/2\sigma^{2}} dx=1$ for al $\sigma >0$.